# EF6 and Lazy Loading, Associated Entity is Null when Validating Changes to Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

This seems pretty odd to me. I am using EF6 to load an entity, alter it, and save it. Simple example below.

The load:

```
 var clientQuery = from x in Context.Clients
                    where x.DateTimeCreated > latest_time
                    orderby x.DateTimeCreated descending, x.IsPosted ascending
                    select x;
        this.Clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>(clientQuery);
        int cnt = this.Clients.Count;
        TotalPages = cnt / itemsPerPage;
        if (cnt % itemsPerPage != 0)
            TotalPages += 1;
        clientViewSource.Source = this.Clients;
```

Client has an associated Entity, for simplicity, we can call it "Case". When this query is loaded, the Cases are loaded as well. I can view selected Client, and its Case and all values. I made a couple of changes to the entity.

```
               this.Client.IsAssigned = true;
               this.Client.AssignedUser = (combo_users.SelectedItem as User);
               this.Context.SaveChanges();
```

I use an IValidatableObject class to ensure all values are valid. However, when checking the 'Client' entity, its associated "Case" is null during validation. Prior to hitting SaveChanges, I have verified that the Context has changes, and that the Client's 'Case' is not null. Am I missing something here, am I expecting a result that is not intended with validations?

Validation example:

```
public partial class Client : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(IsStrategic)
        {
            if(StrategicCase.ExternalLeadSource == null)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult
                ("No external lead source set.", new [] {"StrategicCase.ExternalLeadSource"});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: since you are using lazy loading, why would you need check null in the validation. The cases will be loaded when accessed, if your validation logic doesn't need load cases, then it would be null.

Comment: Do you mean that if, even if the 'Case' is loaded, if it doesn't have any changes specific to the 'Case' entity, it wouldn't be passed as part of the parent 'Client' object to the Validation class?

Comment: I mean, the case is loaded when you try to access it, if you don't access it in your validation logic, it would be null

Comment: I am accessing it in the validation logic, that's why I know that it is null. The validation logic throws an exception when examining the 'Client' entity. Part of the client Entity being its 'Case' and the values of the 'Case'.

Comment: post some code of your validation logic

Comment: In the above validation logic (a snippet of the full class), StrategicCase ('Case') will be null. Even if it is not null and is showing as tracked by the Context.

Comment: I didn't where StrategicCase is loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by how its loaded. Does it need to be re-loaded once inside the Validation? Because it is Lazy Loaded prior to the call to SaveChanges.